# Ruby on Rails multiple methods per page in routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Stupid question... I have two forms with two different functions on one page, my views/projects/new.html.erb file. So far I've only implemented one, with the option to "Create" a new project. I want to add another function to sort the records displayed on the same page, something like:

```
<%= link_to "Category", { :controller => "projects", :action => "sortTable", :filter => "Category" }, :remote => true %>
```

--
My routes.rb file:

```
Docside::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :projects
  resources :categories
  #get "home/index"
  root :to => "projects#new"
  match 'project/new',:controller=>"projects",:action=>"create"
end
```

But I'm getting the error "No route matches {:action=>"sortTable", :controller=>"projects"}". When I tried adding " match 'project/new',:controller=>"projects",:action=>"sortTable" " my other function didn't work, and the create function got screwed up. What should I have instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that:

```
resources :projects do
  collection do
    post :sortTable
  end
end
```

And look at this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

Comment: Thank you! How would I add in the "create" action (in the last line of my routes.rb)?

Comment: The `resources :projects` already created for you route to ProjectsController create action for `POST` HTTP method to `/projects` URL. Check it with `rake routes`. If you want to add additional routes to default RESTful ones, use collection block like it is stated in the answer or member block. For other options look at the guide in the answer. It is really well written.

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one route for a given path and method combination. You're trying to define multiple routes on the same path, so only one of these will work (the first one). You should be ok if you use distinct paths for each of these actions (instead of project/new for all of them. Beware of collisions with your existing routes)

You'll also make you life easier if you stick to rails' conventions (and the code will be easier to read if someone else starts working on it). For example `resources :projects` already creates a route for the create action. Additional actions can be added like so

```
resources :projects do
  collection do
    get :sort_table
  end
end
```

Sets up a collection route (ie one that isn't about a specific project) for the sort_table action and sets up a URL helper for you (sort_table_projects_path). There are alternative syntaxes you can use - I encourage you to have a look at the routing [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)